# Find the last item in array in mongo document and check if its field is a certain value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, helper

I got this document:

```
{
_id: "ZApHZeqw98uhwqaey",
borrowerId: "DmGQyqenbNt4eBMia",
isSeenByOther: 1,
lenderId: "JsJyvseqiiazGxRuq",
messages: [{
   date: Sun Oct 25 2015 19:40:25 GMT+0100 (CET),
   from: "JsJyvseqiiazGxRuq",
   text: "Hi there"
},{
   date: Sun Oct 25 2015 19:40:35 GMT+0100 (CET),
   from: "DmGQyqenbNt4eBMia",
   text: "Hey!"
}]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to just get a boolean value stating whether or not the value of the field `from` of **the last object item in the array: `messages`** is the current user.

I have tried a lot of different mongodb projections such as [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) and [$position](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) which essentially inserts in the beginning of the array but not ideal for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use underscore's [_.last()](http://underscorejs.org/#last) function as follows:

```
var doc = MyCollection.findOne({ _id: "ZApHZeqw98uhwqaey" });
var lastElement = _.last(doc.messages);
if ( lastElement.from === Meteor.userId() ){
  ... do your thing
}
```

Comment: Hi again, the code works when I use it in a global helper, but I keep getting errors in the console nonetheless, which reads like this: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Comment: That means `doc` is undefined which means your `.findOne()` query isn't returning a document. Check your query itself.

Comment: Exactly! That was it. Thanks ;)